# Why are teams required to submit their batting order before the start of play?

Tags: rules, cricket

As per laws of the game, a team can send their batsmen to bat in any order. Why then are teams asked to submit the batting order before start of the game?

See the team nomination forms [tweeted by ICC](https://twitter.com/ICCMediaComms/status/580928710661947393) ahead of the 2015 World Cup semi-final match between India and Australia.

[image: Australia Nomination Form]
[image: India Nomination Form]

Comment: There is no law to submit batting order with team nomination form. Both team just need to submit the playing eleven plus four substitute players. The batting order might be just a formality.

Comment: @hims056 While I fully agree there's no Law of Cricket requiring the batting order, the form references the Match Participating Agreement and the Playing Conditions, and I strongly suspect they will require the batting order. Television likes it.

Comment: Perhaps it's yet another case of Cricket copying Baseball, unbeknownst to everyone.  [EvilSarcasticSmirk]

Answer (score 2):

They're not. The space on the form is optional.

Section 1.2 of the [2015 World Cup Playing Regulations](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/54dad3266e240-CWC2015%20Final%20Update%2028%201%202015.pdf) covers nomination of players - batting order is not mentioned.

As someone said in the comments, the TV people like it, but teams can and do change it at will, as it's a tactical weapon.

Comment: Can you find a copy of the Match Participating Agreement?

Comment: Tried, couldn't. You?

Comment: I can't find it either - and I'm not sure we can definitively say it's not required until we do find it.

Comment: We all know the batting order changes, we've seen it in matches in the last day or two. The teams may be asked to submit the batting order, but it's not adhered to. Possibly, if the form is sent back with no numbers, it'll be rejected, but even if it's fully filled in, it's not reliable.

Comment: I would suggest that it would be an intended batting order, as Happy said there is no law to require it.  The laws simply demand that you name your nominated players prior to the toss. There are lots of reasons why a batsmen may bat in a different position from injury to match situation and all things in between.

Answer (score 1):

Though some answers+comments say that this is optional, there is no source given. So I think this question makes sense.

Here is a possible reason for specifying batting order.

If a batsman is out, and the next batsman has not yet come in within fixed some time, then he is given out. Which batsman is out depends on batting order.

Comment: (A) is actually quite interesting - *who* is timed out if no batsman appears? The [laws](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-31-timed-out-1/) just state "incoming batsman". (B) is missing the point of the question though - it's about why a *batting order* is nominated, not why 11 players have to be nominated for a match - everybody understands why that is there.

Comment: @PhilipKendall , while filling the form for (B) who is a substitute and who is not , it is simple to just put in the batting order and hence solve (A) at the same. Other wise, two forms would be needed, for (A) and (B) separately. So it is tangentially related. Anyway, I have removed that point.

Comment: @PhilipKendall , if (A) is interesting, why would the answer be downvoted ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, so can't directly say - but 1) the (b) from your original answer wasn't relevant and 2) given that "timed out" is so *incredibly* rare in cricket, it seems unlikely to have a entire protocol just for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

In all levels of cricket, it's a courtesy to the scorers and the media (if any) to specify a batting order and a wicket-keeper before the match, but it is not binding during the match.  (The designation of the captain, however, is binding.)

The particular example is from the World Cup, where teams operate with a predefined squad of 15.  So the preprinted sheets ensure that the playing XI and the substitutes are chosen from the set of permitted players.  The batting order is an added convenience.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this?